# writing to multiple files at a time

Tags: c++, file

I want to create multiple files inside a loop and write something into them. I have made the following code. But it only creates one file named '1' instead of five files (from 1 to 5):

```
#include <fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  FILE *fp;
  ofstream os;
  char i;
  char fileName[] = "0.txt";
  for(i='1';i<='5';i++)
  {
     fileName[0]=i;
     .
     os.open (fileName);
     os<<"Hello"<<"\n";
  }
}
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? How will I get the five files?

Comment: is it legal to change this string `"0.txt"` ? Can you edit the question to remove the dot?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's non-`const` `char` array, it's legal.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes because it's copied into a char array.

Comment: Use `ofstream::close` inside loop

Comment: I added `os.close()` and it worked properly, else `os` won't open another file.

Answer (score 2):

The reference for [std::ofstream::open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/) specifically states:

> Open file Opens the file identified by argument filename, associating
>   it with the stream object, so that input/output operations are
>   performed on its content. Argument mode specifies the opening mode.
>
> If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already
>   open), calling this function fails.

You never close the file you're working with in your loop so `open` for the second-fifth time fails.

add it:

```
  for(i='1';i<='5';i++)
  {
     fileName[0]=i;
     os.open (fileName);
     os<<"Hello"<<"\n";
     os.close();
  }
```

Also, you should check if `open()` succeeded:

```
  for(i='1';i<='5';i++)
  {
     fileName[0]=i;
     os.open (fileName);
     if(os) // checks if open() succeeeded
     {
       os<<"Hello"<<"\n";
       os.close();
     }
  }
```

Comment: one should always check return status for `os.open`. Declaring `ofstream os;` inside the loop also does it (no need for `close` in that case)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Not specifically focused on that problem, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream os;
  char fileName[] = "0.txt";
  for(int i = '1'; i <= '5'; i++)
  {
     fileName[0] = i;
     os.open(fileName);
     os << "Hello" << "\n";
     os.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Huh, dozen of similar solutions in a minute =D